# unfunded bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

What should happen if a user offers a bounty but does not have the personal rep to fund it? [The bounty help](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says that bounties are "funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it".

[This bountied question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23767/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-zip-chain-actuators-in-robotics) offers a 100-point bounty, yet [the user](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/29026/fulano) has only 15 rep. As it happens, a review of this user's history shows a broad curiosity but low quality questions.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as an ***unfunded bounty***, from [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) we can see...

- **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

So, the reason they have so little rep is that they spent almost all of it on adding a bounty to their question, which means they must have *really* wanted an answer.

As it is, it's a *Pro's and Con's* question so I've just closed it as *Opinion Based*.